# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'indexer#' and 'indexer#'

Tags: vb.net, ironpython

I'm working on a vb.net project where we are using ironPython for scripting. The vb.net part expose some objects with read only properties to be used in user scripts.

At first when the properties were unparameterized scripts worked just fine. But as soon as we added parameters (with defaults values) calls like `ret = obj1.param1 - obj2.param1` stopped 
to work with the error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'indexer#' and 'indexer#'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IronPython probably doesn't support parameterized properties with default values. Please [open an issue](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create.aspx) with an example VB class.

Comment: I opened an issue over there, and I'll link it here if there is a solution.